# Restrict Dynamics 365 FO endpoint to certain IPs

Tags: microsoft-dynamics, axapta, dynamics-365, dynamics-365-operations

Is there a way to restrict calls to a Microsoft Dynamics 365 FO endpoint to certain IP addresses?

I mean the hXXps://XXXXXX.sandbox.operations.eu.dynamics.com API.

Right now, all that is needed are the app ID, tenant/client ID and secret, and anyone could connect to it. It would be nice if we could limit the access to certain IP addresses to have a bit more protection against leaked credentials.

Comment: If you are just looking at restricting the oData/Custom Service API access, I think you can apply an Azure "conditional access policy" to the Microsoft Entra ID (aka Azure AD) application that you setup for the API access. I don't have admin access in a tenant to try this to confirm for sure.  Make sure you set it up in "report only" mode first so you can analyze the impact before enabling.

Comment: @BateTech Thanks! I’ll give that a try. Actually, we’d like to implement logging for all API requests, so we’re thinking about adding an Azure Function (or API Managament) in front of the OData API. So it wouldn’t be ideal if this could be circumvented. I guess we could also restrict access, so that only that Azure Function (or APIM) would be allowed to call the API?

Comment: It looks like you can get a dedicated IP for an Azure Function so that sounds like it would work if the conditional access policy only allows connections from that IP. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/ip-addresses?tabs=portal#dedicated-ip-addresses